# Equivalent conditions that system of sets is a basis

Tags: general-topology

I am self-studying Topology and read about the basis of a topology.

> Defintion: Let $(X,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space. A system $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{O}$ is called basis if every open set is a union of sets of $\mathcal{B}$.

Now I want to prove the following property which is stated without proof in my book.

> Proposition: A set $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ is a basis of a uniquely defined topology if and only if
>
> 1. The union of all sets of $\mathcal{B}$ is $X$.
> 2. The intersection of two sets of $\mathcal{B}$ is the union of sets of $\mathcal{B}$.

For proving this it seems necessary to explicitly construct the topology with sets of $\mathcal{B}$, e.g. setting $$\mathcal{O}=\{\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i, \ B_i\in \mathcal{B},\ I\text{ arbitrary index set}\}$$ But then I remembered that there were problems when wanting to explicitly state a generated $\sigma$-algebra only using countable set operations, as can be done for just a generated algebra. It is not obvious to me how to work with sets of cardinality greater one and I am wondering if my approach is correct.

Only the uniqueness is clear. If two topologies have the same basis, they are equal.

By the way, a similar property can be stated for the closed sets.

> Proposition: A set $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$ is a basis of a the closed sets with respect to a topology if and only if
>
> 1. The intersection of all sets of $\mathcal{F}$ is $\emptyset$.
> 2. The union of two sets of $\mathcal{B}$ is the intersection of sets of $\mathcal{B}$.

But this time no uniqueness was stated in my book. However, the closed sets of a topology are uniquely defined by a basis of the closed sets. Therefore, the open sets must be unique, too, once a basis of the closed sets is found. So I can add "unique topology" to this statement, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for some topology $\mathcal{O}$, the two conditions 1. and 2. (that do not refer to $\mathcal{O}$, but are "internal" to $\mathcal{B}$) are easily checked :

1. follows from $X$ being open, so it has to be a union of basic open sets, as all sets in $\mathcal{O}$ must be.
2. follows from the fact that, if $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ they are in particular open so their intersection is open too, and so must again be a union of sets from $\mathcal{B}$. This is often further specified as

$$\forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2: \exists B_3 \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$$

which is equivalent to 2.

Both conditions can be entirely checked "within $\mathcal{B}$", as it were, and then it's  not too hard to check that the collection of *all* unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal{B}$ defines a topology on $X$ for which $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis. So these necessary conditions are in fact sufficient and can be used to **define** a topology where we don't have one yet.

The unicity is clear: the set of unions from $\mathcal{B}$ is uniquely determined by the basis.

Comment: So my attempt was correct after all? Is it true what I wrote about the closed sets in my question?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta you had no attempt in your question. The closed sets formulation is a straightforward dual to the open basis part. Closed bases are sometimes considered but are a lot rarer.

Comment: I tried it with all possible unions of elements of the basis, so I guess this is the same as you did. Yes, but the topology is also uniquely defined by a basis of closed sets, correct?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta the closed sets determine the topology as well etc. So sure.